# Python - replacing a pattern in a string

Tags: python, string, replace, token

I have strings which contains certain words with the following form:

```
'something1__something2__need'
```

for example here is a full string with those words:

```
'bla__wewe__23,sad__fd__sas po__oop__retq2'
```

I want to extract a new string with only the last sub-word in each word in the string, meaning that my first example turns into `'need'` and the second into `'23,sas retq2'`. Possible delimiters are spaces and commas. Should be without loops if possible.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what a word-boundary and a "sub-word" boundary are in your case. Then you can easily solve this via a regular expression.

Comment: @TommyF words are everything between commas and spaces and sub-words are the words between '__'.

Comment: Single Regex solution: `_([^_,]+)([,\s]|\Z)` your result is in the first capture group. Paste it here with your testdata to get an explanation: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re

s = ['something1__something2__need', 'bla__wewe__23,sad__fd__sas po__oop__retq2']
for i in s:
    val = re.split(r"([,\s])", i)     #Split by space, comma
    print("".join(j.split("__")[-1] for j in val))    #Split by __ and join by last element in list.
```

**Output:**

```
need
23,sas retq2
```